# Convert a number into a name

Tags: javascript, html, numbers, converters, names

For example, I have `<span id="convertNumberToName">1</span>` somewhere on my page.
Notice the "1", I want to covert "1" into let's say "John" every time the "1" is within a span tag with "convert" as the id.

I also want "2" to be converted to "Pete". And "3" to be converted to "Bob".

So if my html is:

```
<span id="convertNumberToName">1</span>
<span id="convertNumberToName">2</span>
<span id="convertNumberToName">3</span>
```

My page reads:

**John**
**Pete**
**Bob**

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will convert the numbers into your chosen names.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

    var e = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

    for (var i = 0, l = e.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (typeof e[i].className !== 'undefined' && e[i].className === 'convertNumberToName') {
            e[i].innerHTML = convertToName(e[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }

    function convertToName(n) {
        var names = ['John', 'Pete', 'Bob'],
            n = parseInt(n, 10) - 1;

        if (names[n]) {
            return names[n];
        }

        return 'Unknown';
    }

};  
</script>
```

```
<span class="convertNumberToName">1</span><br />
<span class="convertNumberToName">2</span><br />
<span class="convertNumberToName">3</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

shorter way to do this >

```
<script>
var names = ['John', 'Pete', 'Bob'];
var div = document.getElementById('convertNumberToName');
div.innerHTML = names[div.innerHTML];
</script>
```

Comment: You should change to div.innerHTML = names[div.innerHTML - 1];